# LiveData's map function using SavedStateHandle isn't called correctly and returns null

Tags: android, background, android-livedata

I saved input to LiveData using SavedStateHandle.
Then, using LiveData.map{}, I created a LiveData returns a validation result by calling UseCase for the input whenever the input value changes.
Normally, it works well, but it didn't work well when returning to the app after moving to the device background when set `Don't keep activities` mode and the `Background process limit` 1.
As a result of debugging, input was well saved in LiveData(as savedStateHandle's), but the Validation check LiveData value mapping input was null.
Is there any way to solve this problem?